# $\lim\limits_{h\to0} \frac{(x+h)^3 -x^3}{h}$ Compute the following limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I can not seem to figure out the direction to go with this problem. I'm not quite sure how to break it up.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$(x+h)^3-x^3 = 3x^2h + 3xh^2 + h^3$$
Hence,
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^3-x^3}h = \lim_{h \to0} \dfrac{3x^2h + 3xh^2 + h^3}h = \lim_{h \to 0}\left(3x^2+3xh+h^2\right) = 3x^2$$

Answer (score 3):

Just expand the cube:
$$
(x+h)^3=
(x+h)^2\times (x+h)=
(x^2 + 2xh + h^2)\times (x+h) =\dots 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out here that $(x+h)^3 = x^3+3x^2h+3xh^2+h^3$.

Here's different approach.  Recall that $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.  Consequently
\begin{align}
(x+h)^3-x^3 & = \Big((x+h)-x\Big)\Big( (x+h)^2 +(x+h)x + x^2 \Big) \\[12pt]
& = h\Big( (x+h)^2 +(x+h)x + x^2 \Big).
\end{align}

Now we might be tempted to do the routine simplifications of the expression in the large parentheses, but it's quicker to do this:
$$
\frac{(x+h)^3-x^3} h = \frac{h\Big( (x+h)^2 +(x+h)x + x^2 \Big)} h = (x+h)^2 +(x+h)x + x^2.
$$
We want the limit of *that* as $h\to0$, and *now* we can just plug in $h=0$ and get $x^2+x^2+x^2$.